# How do I export comments from Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos

In Google Photos, is there a way to export a text file that contains a list of photos (filenames) and their associated comments?

My client has left comments on a large selection of photos to be edited.  It will be extremely time-consuming to manually copy out the comments and the matching filenames.

I can see the comments in "My Activity", but I would like to export the information so I can easily determine the photos (filenames) that match the comments.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Google Takeout to download your photos data, it will include the comments in JSON format.

Select Photos only on the takeout page, and hit the faint V next to the switch to have the option to select a number of recent albums only. Then scroll to the bottom and press Next and start archiving. Then you can download a zip containing these albums including the text comments.